# Firestore as true Multi-Region database

Tags: database, database-design, google-cloud-firestore

Currently Firestore is multi-region within US and Europe but is there any way to handle firestore queries from all parts of the world?

Consider an app which has userbase distributed globally. In this scenario, as firestore is hardcoded with a specific region at the start of the project, how can we handle this scenario?

What are the available ways to have better latencies from all regions?

Example:

## 1 Request

```
  User from US + Firestore in US => It will be in range of 100ms
  User from India + Firestore in US => It will be in range of 300ms (includes RTT)
```

## 5 Requests

```
 User from US + Firestore in US => It will be in range of 500ms
 User from India + Firestore in US => It will be in range of 2.5-3Secs (includes RTT)
```

As you can see the latencies from a different location will be too high in some instances.

What are the possible alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no simple configuration to get Firestore to operate uniformly across multiple geographic regions.  You can only do what's mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/locations) without managing things yourself.

If you absolutely must have Firestore data in multiple geographic regions, you would need to:

1. Create a new project for each region, since Firestore can only exist in one region per project
2. Mirror the data from a "master" project into the projects in other regions
3. Require that only the "master" region be written to, while reads can come from anywhere

Comment: I see the complexity. Master in the middle (Europe) would be a good choice?

Comment: You should benchmark it and pick what's for your expected use cases.

Comment: Thanks doug! Also any close relevant database you are aware on GCP which can handle multiple geographic regions effectively?